# fast way of query from multiple database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two identical databases db1 with table name product1 and db2 with table name product2 respectively. With Column say id,name,price for both tables.

I stored products with price less than 500 in db1 product1 table and products with price more than 500 in db2 product2 table.

Now I need to Combine the result of both databases and sort it by name. I used following SQL Query in MYSQL.

```
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,name,price from db1.product1
                  UNION ALL  
                  SELECT id,name,price from db2.product2) AS DATA 
   ORDER BY DATA.name LIMIT 18
```

It works fine for me expect it took more time than expected.

Is there any other fastest way to do this job?

Thanks for giving your precious time.

Comment: Why do you have such a daft system?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other fastest way to do this job?

Generally don't do this.  Put everything into one well-designed database.  There are cases that need special treatment but the single DB is the best starting approach.

If you're absolutely sure there is a performance problem you can look at partitioning.  Even then, it's generally more useful as an administration tool than a general performance one, though it will have specific benefits.

Most of us don't work on data that requires anything like dual databases for performance.  I'd concentrate on making a correct single instance first.  (i.e. single DB, single table)

Specifically though, structuring your query along these lines may improve performance

```
SELECT * FROM (
select * from (SELECT id,name,price from db1.product1    ORDER BY DATA.name LIMIT 18) as X
UNION ALL  
select * from (SELECT id,name,price from db2.product2    ORDER BY DATA.name LIMIT 18) as Y 
) AS DATA 
   ORDER BY DATA.name LIMIT 18
```

that way you're only asking the minimum of each DB.

Comment: My service provider Godaddy doesn't allow me to create a database with size more than 1 GB. So sadly I have to do this(create multiple databases). which decreased my execution time from 2s to 10s.

Comment: Well you might then want to pick a tech provider that meets your needs, not try and mash your needs to match the tech available.  That rarely ends well.

Comment: does create view will help me?

Comment: No a view will not help in any way.  Try the suggestion in my edited answer.

Comment: nope, it won't work because I used where clause with multiple conditions at the end. You were right need to change my service provider or recode the whole system Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand your comments about multiple conditions. I responded to the question asked. If you want to update the question to better reflect what you want you might get more relevant help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple calls to mysql_connect(), but if the parameters are the same you need to pass true for the '$new_link' (fourth) parameter, otherwise the same connection is reused. For example:

```
$dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
$dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 

mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2);
```

Then to query database 1 pass the first link identifier:

```
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh1);
```

and for database 2 pass the second:

```
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh2);
```

Other options

If the MySQL user has access to both databases and they are on the same host (i.e. both DBs are accessible from the same connection) you could:

1. Keep one connection open and call mysql_select_db() to swap between
   as necessary. I am not sure this is a clean solution and you could
   end up querying the wrong database.
2. Specify the database name when you reference tables within your
   queries (e.g. SELECT * FROM database2.tablename). This is likely to
   be a pain to implement.

Also please read troelskn's answer because that is a better approach if you are able to use PDO rather than the older extensions.